# Integral of upper incomplete gamma function

Tags: gamma-function, gamma-distribution

Can anyone please help me with the integral below. I would like to know whether the following relation is correct?

$\int\big(\frac{t}{A}\big)^{n-1}\exp\big(-\frac{t}{A}\big) dt = -A\Gamma(n, \frac{t}{A})$

where $\Gamma(n, \frac{t}{A})$ is the upper incomplete gamma.

Best,

Comment: This is correct. Do it faster using $t=A x$